# Type hinting on multi-type

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have the following function:

```
def pops(L: list, default=None):
    "Pop from the left of the list, or return the default."
    return L.pop(0) if L else default
```

What would be the proper way to add type-hints for this? `L` is a `list` -- I know that (though of what I have no idea). But `default` could be anything -- and by extension, the output could be anything as well. What would be the best way to do this?

Examples:

```
>>> pops([1,2,3,4])
# 1
>>> pops(['1'])
# '1'
>>> pops([], {})
# {}
>>> pops([], None)
# None
```

Comment: Do you mean ```L``` is a list of strings? Because ```str``` doesn't have a ```pop``` method in python.

Comment: `L` is a list ?

Comment: @kaya3 yes updated.

Comment: I don't tend to use type annotations in Python, but in Typescript I would write this with two overload signatures, `pops<S>(arr: S[]): S | undefined` and `pops<S,T>(arr: S[], default: T): S | T`. Hopefully that makes enough sense to be translatable to Python - the idea is to use generic types in order to describe the relationship between the arguments and return type. Not sure if Python allows overload signatures, though.

Comment: @HenryEcker yes updated, I had a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use a `TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar).

```
from typing import List, Union, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
K = TypeVar('K')
def pops(L: List[T], default: K = None) -> Union[T, K, None]:
    "Pop from the left of the list, or return the default."
    return L.pop(0) if L else default
```

Comment: thanks, is there a shorthand for "Any" though? For example, the user could literally pass any type to default, even something non-standard like `decimal.Decimal`.

Comment: Yes. ```from typing import Any```

Comment: @green -- excellent, thank you. On a separate note, what tool do you use for static type checking in your editor (I'm looking for one now that I'm starting to use typing stuff).

Comment: @David542 By my understanding `TypeVar` implicitly has a type of `Any`, though additional arguments can be given to the constructor to specify a more specific type (e.g. `TypeVar('N', int, float)` would be equivalent to a `Union[int, float]` for most purposes). If you wanted to be explicit you could probably use `from typing import Any; T = TypeVar('T', Any)`, but it's probably not necessary

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy `Union[T, K]` is sufficient for the return type?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM `Union[T, K]` would probably be sufficient, but I like to be explicit about the possibility of a `None` return in case the end-user of the code is some shmuck who forgets to nullcheck the return value. Most linters are probably smart enough to intuit it anyway, but I don't have enough experience to be certain about that.